# Sychronous request\response JMS Communication, How to get rid of response messages from JMS Queue after timeout

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms

All,

We have a synchronous JMS communication in place where we send a request to a Queue and wait for the corelated response with timeout of 400 milliseconds. If the response doesnt come back within 400 seconds then our thread timesout and the message remains on Queue and is never read.

Our destination system is taking a lot of time to process messages and the response are coming back after 400 milliseconds resulting in our thread timing out and the Response queue quickly gets full.

How can i get rid of such orphan response messages from the response queue where the response came in late?

Comment: that's what "time to live" is usually used for.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, in JMS protocol, you can set JMSExpiration which is JMS header attribute. If you use standard java-jms, JmsSender class have "setTimeToLive" method that you can use.

https://jms-spec.java.net/2.0/apidocs/